# Different pitch accent patterns of もっとも?

Tags: pronunciation, pitch-accent

The word もっとも has a few different uses. For example, jisho.org lists the following:

> **最も（もっとも）**
>
> Adverb
>
> 1. most; extremely
>
> Other forms
>
> 最も ​【もとも​】、尤も ​【もっとも​】、尤も ​【もとも​】

---

> **尤も（もっとも）**
>
> Conjunction
>
> 1. but then; although; though (Usually written using kana alone)
>
> Na-adjective, Noun
>
> 1. reasonable; natural; just (Usually written using kana alone)

According to super daijirin, these words have the following pitch accent patterns:

最も: もっとも{LHHL}

尤も: もっとも{LHHL} **or** もっとも{HLLL}

Considering that 尤も has these two potential pitch accent patterns, when should もっとも be pronounced as もっとも{LHHL}, and when should it be pronounced as もっとも{HLLL}?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [最も](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E6%9C%80%E3%82%82) and [尤も](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E5%B0%A4%E3%82%82) are identical in terms of pitch accent. They are both pronounced もっとも【LHHL】. As an exception, [御尤も](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E5%BE%A1%E5%B0%A4%E3%82%82) is a fixed expression that is pronounced like ごもっとも【LHLLL】 (the kanji is rarely used).

Comment: Okay, so maybe the alternate pronunciation of 尤も is actually a reference to its use in 御尤も.